# python unittest module not found

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have following sample code:

```py
import unittest
from src.util.screenshoter import Screenshooter 

class TestScreenshoter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_random_test(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And src/util/screenshoter.py

```py
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

...
```

When I try running the test I get a following error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyscreenshot'`. despite running earlier `pip install pyscreenshot`

When I run screenshoter.py I don't get any errors.

Comment: Since you wrote venv in title, do you need to activate virtualenv?

Comment: @MilosStojanovic my bad, removed it from title. it was there to just point out that the question is about module that was installed via pip into virtualenv.

Comment: Are you sure you used the virtual environment's `pip`, and not a globally installed `pip`, to install the module, and that you are using the same environment to run both the script and the tests?

Comment: And was there a time when it worked and you changed something or is this the first try?

Comment: Okay so for some reason my VSCode stopped using virtualenv when running tests despite it being activated. Stupid mistake by me

Answer (score -1):

Adjust the Python Path

```
import sys
import os

# Add the src directory to the Python path

 sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../')))
```

This code snippet adds the parent directory of the test file (which should be the root of your project) to the Python path.